# How to disable the "some site wants to open this application" alert in Chrome using Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

How to block this pop-up?

[image: pop-up]

An English equivalent would be:

> This site is trying to open Spotify.
>
> https://open.spotify.com wants to open this application.
>
> □ Always allow open.spotify.com to open links of this type in the associated app

I tried to use:

```py
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
options.add_argument('--disable-popup-blocking')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When running the Selenium webdriver, Chrome opens a new browsing session with the default Chrome profile (without any custom settings).

To get around this, you can set a profile directory by using the `--user-data-dir=/your/profile/data/location` argument. In this location Chrome will create a new profile location. When your script is running, manually navigate to the Chrome window that should have opened on your screen and simply enable the *always open* option.

The next time you run your script using the same profile directory you shouldn't see this pop-up.

Comment: how to make it not open in the application? reappears when canceled a second time

Comment: Do you mean that the alert is now gone but you just don't want to see the browser being opened? You can try using [`--headless`](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/headless-chrome/) argument in chrome's options.